# Bound Apps-Script doesn't copy when using template gallery

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs

I created a document and wrote a bound apps script code to add a custom menu item that, when selected, runs a function to generate a blank table at the top of the document.

The code runs as intended when the original document is opened, and the bound script copies when "Make a Copy" is used to duplicate the document.

I'd like all members of my organization to be able to take advantage of this simple functionality. I added the document with the bound script to the template gallery, however when you select the document from the template gallery the bound code does not get copied to the new document. When I go back to the template gallery and click "edit" on the underlying document, the bound code is present and the custom menu appears and functions.

Is there a way to create a document with a bound script and turn it into a template so that other users can create new documents with the expanded functionality the bound script provides?